# How can I get this impossible 3x3 cube back to a solvable state?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I have a 3x3 cube that I'm pretty certain is in an invalid state. A lot of the advice online is to disassemble the cube and put it back together, but it's a rubiks.com cube and I can't find any good instructions on how to take it apart. I don't believe it was ever fully disassembled, but maybe a corner or two or more got twisted along the way. Is there any way to twist some number of corners to get this back into a solvable state? I've come across information about the various parities, but I'm struggling to understand them enough to apply it to this particular situation.

[image: invalid cube]

Comment: Well, it's possible to use OLL to reorient the red faces (case 24 in [this OLL guide](https://jperm.net/algs/oll)), but I'm not sure if the PLL case after that is possible.

Comment: "...I can't find any good instructions on how to take it apart."  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+disassemble+a+rubik%27s+cube

Comment: Note that just taking the some centre caps off and putting them back incorrectly can also lead to this situation. Pop off all four centre caps of the middle layer, and put the green cap in the red face, red cap in the blue face, blue cap in the orange face, orange cap in the green face - so they are all moved along by one face. The cube will then be solvable.

Comment: @WeatherVane That question seems to confirm it's impossible as-is, but the instructions at the end say to disassemble it and reassemble and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: *"I don't believe it was ever fully disassembled"* one way it could have got like that is by prising out the two misplaced corners (which is easier if the face is twisted to 45°) and slot them back in correctly.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The first youtube videos that both claim to work for "ANY" 3x3 cube both explicitly say they will not give instructions for the Rubik's brand cube (one of them mentions that it's extremely difficult and he's never actually gotten one apart).  If I pry up the pieces a bit, there appears to be some sort of white-ball-ish mechanism inside -- and none of the instructions or videos that I've come across look quite like this one.  If you have any specific videos/instructions in mind, I'm happy to give them a try.

Comment: The Rubik's brand is generally more difficult to disassemble due to its rigidity—modern cubes have springs for some elasticity for solving, and _extra_-modern cubes use maglev.

Comment: @Someone I tried the OLL steps you suggested, but I think I messed up somewhere along the way and ended up with a fairly scrambled cube.  Since I don't know the full history of this cube, at that point I decided to go deeper down the path of disassembly. 

I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXQMJx61kP0  This looks to be pretty similar to the one I'm working with and I was able to finally get out an edge piece after lifting it up, pulling the corners away and lifting more on the edge piece.  Once that initial piece was out, it wasn't hard to get more out.

Comment: @ChrisWeber  You're right.  Sorry.  I missed the whole "Rubik's brand" thing.